# Collapse/Expand menu N-level using RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have a list category ((N- level), each category have a list sub-category, each sub-category have other list sub-category...

I want to use RecyclerView to Collapse/Expand list category((N- level). Can I do it? What the best way to do Collapse/Expand list n-level? (It same category in LAZADA-shopping & deals app on PlayStore)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's called ExpandableRecyclerView. There are some libraries that may help you.

- [expandable-recycler-view](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)
- [Expandable RecyclerView](https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/)